# How to find the intersection of two ellipses in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, intersection, ellipse

I have two equations:

```
ellipseOne = '((x-1)^2)/6^2 + y^2/3^2 = 1';
```

and

```
ellipseTwo = '((x+2)^2)/2^2 + ((y-5)^2)/4^2 = 1';
```

and I plotted them:

```
ezplot(ellipseOne, [-10, 10, -10, 10])
hold on
ezplot(ellipseTwo, [-10, 10, -10, 10])
title('Ellipses')
hold off
```

Now I'm trying to find the intersection of the two ellipses. I tried:

```
intersection = solve(ellipseOne, ellipseTwo)
intersection.x
intersection.y
```

to find the points where they intersect, but MATLAB is giving me a matrix and an equation as an answer which I don't understand. Could anyone point me in the right direction to get the coordinates of intersection?

Comment: The way you're using solve here is incorrect; the call is supposed to be S = solve(eqn,var). The easiest way to handle this, since both equations are equal to 1, is to set the two equations equal to each other and subtract. So ellipseDiff = '((x-1)^2)/6^2 + y^2/3^2 -((x+2)^2)/2^2 - ((y-5)^2)/4^2 = 0'.

Comment: @IanRiley The general use of `solve` is actually `S = solve(eqn1, eqn2, ... eqnM, var1, var2, ... varN);`.  This use is actually correct.  Omitting any `var*` variables automatically determines what the variables are.  However, the current documentation of `solve` has it the way you stated... which is rather weird.  Doing `help solve` in MATLAB R2015b gives me the first way of invocation.  I'm assuming that the first way will be eventually deprecated, but its use is still correct here.

Comment: Huh; weird to find such a deficiency in the documentation. Thanks for the tip @rayryeng

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The solution is in symbolic form.  The last step you need to take is to transform it into numeric.  Simply convert the result using `double`.  However, because this is a pair of quadratic equations, there are 4 possible solutions due to the sign ambiguity (i.e. `+/-`) and can possibly give imaginary roots.  Therefore, isolate out the real solutions and what is left should be your answer.

Therefore:

```
% Your code
ellipseOne = '((x-1)^2)/6^2 + y^2/3^2 = 1';
ellipseTwo = '((x+2)^2)/2^2 + ((y-5)^2)/4^2 = 1';
intersection = solve(ellipseOne, ellipseTwo);

% Find the points of intersection
X = double(intersection.x);
Y = double(intersection.y);
mask = ~any(imag(X), 2) | ~any(imag(Y), 2);
X = X(mask); Y = Y(mask);
```

The first three lines of code are what you did.  The next four lines extract out the roots in numeric form, then I create a `logical` mask that isolates out only the points that are real.  This looks at the imaginary portion of both the `X` and `Y` coordinate of all of the roots and if there is such a component for any of the roots, we want to eliminate those.  We finally remove the roots that are imaginary and we should be left with two real roots.

We thus get for our intersection points:

```
>> disp([X Y])
   -3.3574    2.0623
   -0.2886    2.9300
```

The first column is the `X` coordinate and the second column is the `Y` coordinate.  This also seems to agree with the plot.  I'll take your ellipse plotting code and also insert the intersection points as blue dots using the above solution:

```
ezplot(ellipseOne, [-10, 10, -10, 10])
hold on
ezplot(ellipseTwo, [-10, 10, -10, 10])
% New - place intersection points
plot(X, Y, 'b.');
title('Ellipses');
hold off;
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you very much

Comment: How to find one ellipse is inside another?

Comment: @manoos I see your question now. It's unfortunately out of scope with this question. You need to ask a new one. If you already did ask, send me a link.

Comment: @rayryeng: Could you please reply on this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56927210/how-can-i-check-one-ellipse-is-inside-the-another-ellipse-by-using-matlab?noredirect=1#comment100396679_56927210