# How can I check one ellipse is inside the another ellipse by using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, geometry, ellipse

I am trying to find the status of two ellipses.

I tried to find the intersection of two ellipses by using the following code:

```
syms x y
a=4;
b=2;
ellipse1 = ((x+10).^2/a.^2)+(y.^2/b.^2)==1;
a1=6;
b1=5;
ellipse2 = ((x-10).^2/a1.^2)+(y.^2/b1.^2)==1;
c = solve(ellipse1,ellipse2);

dX = double(c.x);
dY = double(c.y);
```

If ellipses are not interesting, I get the imaginary values solution. There can be two chances for an imaginary solution as shown below:

[image: Seperated Ellipses]

[image: One ellipse is inside the another]

How can I find the ellipses are intersecting or not? If not intersecting, what will be the positions of ellipses( inside or separated) ?
Can anyone reply?

Thanks in advance !
Manu

Comment: Take any two points on the two ellipses and evaluate the other ellipse function at those points. If both are outside (i.e. both return a value greater than 1), you have case 1, otherwise you have case 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's say you already know that the ellipses don't intersect (i.e. you got an imaginary values solution from the `solve()` function).

Check whether the center `(x1,x2)` of ellipse1 is inside ellipse2

```
((x1-c1).^2/a1.^2)+((y1-d1).^2/b1.^2) < 1
```

where `(c1,d1)` is the center of **ellipse2**

- If it is, you have case two.
- Otherwise, you have case one.

We know this because

- if any part of the interior of **ellipse1** is inside the interior of
  **ellipse2**
- and we know the two ellipses do not intersect,

> Then one ellipse must be completely contained in the other

**Note:** we don't know which ellipse is inside the other based on this test.